# encoding jboss 7

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, jboss

I tried all possible answers [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228764/jboss-7-encoding-not-working-as-expected) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226018/jboss-encoding-utf-8) , but it didn't worked for me. Now writing the question.

```
private String convertValue(String val){
    System.out.println("convert input:" + val);
    String res = "";
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(val,",");
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
        String token = st.nextToken();
        if (token.matches("([0-9]*)")) {
            char c = (char)Integer.parseInt(token);
            res+=c;
        }else{
            res+=token;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("convert output:" + res);
    return res;
}
```

When running out of the jboss 7 it gives:

```
convert input:61,1087,1088,1080,1074,1077,1090
convert output:=привет
```

Running in the jboss 7 by action:

```
convert input:61,1087,1088,1080,1074,1077,1090
convert output:=??????
```

Why it is not working properly?

My standalone.xml:

```
 <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
</extensions>

<system-properties>
    <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING" value="true"/>
</system-properties>
```

added java opts(-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8):

```
convert input:61,1087,1088,1080,1074,1077,1090
convert output:=–ø—Ä–∏–≤–µ—Ç
```

EDIT 1: My environment:

```
Mac OS X Version 10.7.5
JBoss 7.1.1.Final
java version "1.6.0_33"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_33-b03-424-11M3720)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.8-b03-424, mixed mode)
```

EDIT 2: Code snippet above working in javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped back bean controller when pressing button from JSF page.

Comment: Have you tried writing it to a file instead to check if it might be a problem with the console itself?

Comment: It's not clear where you're seeing the output, in particular.

Comment: Where is the convertValue method called? Is it servlet, jsp, something else? Could you provide a code sample?

Comment: update the question with how the `convertValue` is receiving the `val`

Comment: hardcoded string of integers

Comment: I'm also experiencing a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this in your standalone.conf:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

It worked for me when the direct option for the vm did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Mac, but [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415597/java-how-to-detect-and-change-encoding-of-system-console) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616915/java-console-charset-translation) show that in your case such a code should work:

```
private String convertValue(String val){
    System.out.println("convert input:" + val);
    String res = "";
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(val,",");
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
        String token = st.nextToken();
        if (token.matches("([0-9]*)")) {
            char c = (char)Integer.parseInt(token);
            res+=c;
        }else{
            res+=token;
        }
    }

    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
    out.println("convert output:" + res);
    return res;
}
```