# System does not support the specified encoding

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, encoding, jboss

My project has one page, but when i am trying to access that page through weblogic server it was working  absolutely fine but when i am trying to access the same page with help of jboss, i am getting error like system doesn't support the specific encoding.

Below is the code :-

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var properties_xmlDoc = null; 
var pwPrefix = 'password_';

    function loadProperties() 
    { 
        var oXSLContainer = findObject("propertiesXSL");
        var oXMLContainer = findObject("propertiesXML");
        var oHTMLContainer = findObject("propertiesContainer");
        var sortPropertiesXSL = findObject("sortPropertiesXSL");
        if (properties_xmlDoc == null) 
        {
            properties_xmlDoc = loadXMLFromString(oXMLContainer.value);   
        }

        properties_xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject(sortPropertiesXSL, properties_xmlDoc);

        findObject("propertiesXML").value = properties_xmlDoc.xml;

        oHTMLContainer.innerHTML = new String(properties_xmlDoc.transformNode(oXSLContainer));   


        #if($inlinePropertiesEditor) 
            findObject("propValueDiv").innerHTML = findObject("propertyValueString").innerHTML;   
        #end

    }
```

i am trying to debug this page with the help of IE debugger the below line throwing error as:- "System does not support the specified encoding"

properties_xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject(sortPropertiesXSL, properties_xmlDoc);

Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: You have some problem in loading the Xml. Ex. Special chars. The server may send the xml doc in a different encoding (Utf-8/Utf-16)

Comment: @Vivasaayi-- is there any way to find out in which encoding format server is sending xml...

Comment: You can verify that using Fiddler. (You will see it in the response header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8)

You can check the following links for setting the correct encoding for JBOSS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228764/jboss-7-encoding-not-working-as-expected    
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/190925?start=0&tstart=0&_sscc=t